# Run a powershell script on a selected list item in SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell

Right now I am looking for a way to run a PowerShell script on a "selected" list item in a sharepoint online list.

Every code snippet I see points to running code on the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal, there is no relation between the PowerShell and the Selected Items in the list in GUI.

So in your case,  you can Use **[Where](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** clause based on **specific criteria** to run the PowerShell cmdlet on specific list items on your list.

**Ex:**

```
$listItems = $list.Items| where {$_['column name'] -eq 'True'}
```

Then for-each for each item in `$listItems` as the following

```
$listItems | ForEach-Object {
   #Cmdlets
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do it use the "copy to" menu option to do this while keeping the reference Item ID intact