# Row level permission in a SharePoint list for different user groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions

I have a SharePoint list and I have three groups that access the list to contribute/edit it.

I want to limit access of people at row level. Group A should only see records where col(A) = "AAA". Group B should only see records where col(B) = "BBB". Group C should be able to view and edit every record.
I have already built the groups, but I don't know how to prepare the row level permission for these three groups.
Can you please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have item level permission. And for your scenario, you will need to make unique permissions on each item. Using PowerShell will save time and work. However, if you have hundreds or thousands of items in that list, it may cause a performance issue due to the large number of unique permissions.

PowerShell Reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-grant-permission-to-list-item-using-powershell.html

[Run a powershell script on a selected list item in SharePoint online list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231685/run-a-powershell-script-on-a-selected-list-item-in-sharepoint-online-list)